# How to handle URL with AppDelegate in Swift5.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, xcode12

I'm **looking to handle** a url like "myApp://oauth-callback/xxxx"

In **Swift 5.3** we no longer have an "**AppDelegate**" file and the documentation is now obsolete.
So I did this by following different documentation but it **does not work**... my *print* never appears

Any ideas ? (I am a beginner)

Thanks

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey  : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print("open via url")
        if url.host == "oauth-callback" {
            OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
        }
        
      return true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **onOpenURL** on **ContentView**

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    print("URL")
                    print(url)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement **`scene(_:openURLContexts:)`** method in your **`SceneDelegate`**.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        print(url)
        if url.host == "oauth-callback" {
            OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have SceneDelegate in swift 5.3 / Xcode 12

**SceneDelegate** & **AppDelegate** have been replaced  by single file **NameApp.swift**